# How can i set a Component property to undefined?

Tags: qt, properties, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

I have a property of type `Component`.

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {
    id: root
    property Component sourceComponent
    /* ........ */
    Loader {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: myLoader
    }
    SequentialAnimation {
        id: hideLoader
        NumberAnimation {
            target: root
            property: "y"
            duration: 1000; from: 0; to: -root.height
        }
        onStopped: root.sourceComponent = undefined;  //<-- Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QQmlComponent*
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to set it to `undefined` it raises an error. How can I set it to `undefined`?
 **UPDATE**
As you can see in my sample code, I want to assign `sourceComponent` of the `loader` after finishing the animation. So I need property to be normal not `alias`.

Comment: Why do you want to assign undefined?

Comment: Try assigning null.

Comment: You could set `myLoader.active = false` if you want to unload the loader.

Comment: @eyllanesc because I want to unload loader from out side same way as Loader

Comment: @eyllanesc Loader needs to be set as `undefined`. assigning `null` will not causes unload.

Comment: @eyllanesc setting it to `null` seems to works but is it OK? the documentation says to set `sourceComponent` to `undefined` to destroy current item, freeing resources, leaving Loader empty.

Comment: @GrecKo the documentation says to set `sourceComponent` to `undefined` to destroy current item, freeing resources, leaving Loader empty. So is it enough to setting `active` property `false`? is it same affect as setting `sourceComponent` to `undefined`?

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi the documention of `active` says "Setting the value to inactive will cause any item loaded by the loader to be released, but will not affect the source or sourceComponent.", so yes.

Answer (score 1):

[Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) documentation says:

> If the `source` or `sourceComponent` changes, any previously instantiated items are destroyed. Setting `source` to an empty string or setting `sourceComponent` to `undefined` destroys the currently loaded object, freeing resources and leaving the Loader empty.

So, you can simply set its `source` property an empty string.

In your case, you would need an *alias* property called `sourceComponent`, not a normal property.

```
property alias sourceComponent: myLoader.sourceComponent
```

Comment: Thank you. You can see an animation in my sample code. I want to assign `sourceComponent` of the `loader` after completion of the animation. So I need to get it as a normal property and affect it at a proper time.

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi That animation only operates on `y` property of `root`, can't see anything related to `sourceComponent` of `root`.

Comment: you can see last line of the `hideLoader` animation which handles `onStopped` signal. I will run this animation in some places. Also I want to implement and custom component (above code as a sample) which could handle any value as a `sourceComponent` as a regular Loader one.

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi Please note that by unsetting `root.sourceComponent` you're not unsetting that of that Loader, so this may cause an unexpected behavior. On the other hand I can't see something wrong with `alias` property. That way, unsetting `root.sourceComponent` will unset `mylaoder.sourceComponent` too. But yours wont.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic object creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) to achieve this.

> property Component sourceComponent

Instead of defining `sourceComponent` as `Component`, define it as a `var`. Example :

```
property var sourceComponent = Qt.createComponent("YourCustomImplementation.qml");
```

Assign this sourceComponent to your Loader sourceComponent.

```
myLoader.sourceComponent = root.sourceComponent
```